# How can I call function of another Bundle in AEM?

Tags: osgi, adobe, bundle, aem

I have two bundle,X and Y.Both of them were installed and active as bundle on OSGi.Function sayHello in Bundle X and function writeHello in Bundle Y.I need to call sayHello function from Bundle Y and I will write returned string with writeHello function in Bundle Y.
Can you say that it is possible or not?If it is possible how can deploy this logic?
In my mind,I have something for example;
I will add dependency of Bundle X in pom of Bundle Y,but how can I see function sayHello after adding dependency?

Thank you..

Comment: Have you read anything at all about OSGi before posting this question? Any books or tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to access a functionality of another bundle. For both ways you need an Export-Package in the bundle offering the class and an Import-Package for the package of the external classes you want to use.

1. Create an instance of the class and use it
   Use this approach if the class you want to use is simple to setup and you do not need decoupling. This is a typical case for simple libraries.
2. Publish the functionality as an OSGi service and bind the service
   Use this approach if it is difficult to instantiate the class and you do not want the client to be involved with this. The service approach also makes sense if you want to decouple from the implementation. To achieve this you create an interface for the functionality and publish the service with the interface. The client can then bind the service by specifying only the interface.

Comment: Can you please share some example of doing what you have mentioned above.